# Getting results of grep / xargs onto separate lines

Tags: bash, xpath, grep, xargs, xmllint

I have a bunch of files.  I grep for a keyword and pass the filenames that contain the keyword to an xmllint which performs an XPath expression to return part of the various the files.

```
grep -irl "keyword" . | xargs xmllint --xpath '/HTML/BODY/P[2]'
```

Problem is there are several files that have the keyword and hence several results to the various xmllint executions. I want to see the result of each xpath on a different line. But they are all amalgamated onto the same line.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-n1` in `xargs` to make sure only `file is passed to`xargs` at a time:

```
grep -irl "keyword" . | xargs -n 1 xmllint --xpath '/HTML/BODY/P[2]'
```

If you want more finer control over output of `xargs` then use a while loop with process substitution:

```
while read -r file; do
    echo "Processing $file =>"
    xmllint --xpath '/HTML/BODY/P[2]' "$file
    echo "==========================="
done < <(grep -irl "keyword" .)
```

Comment: -n 1 works for something like echo. grep -irl "keyword" . | xargs -n 1 echo but doesn't make the outputs of the xmlints go onto new lines

Comment: You can use my while loop based solution for controlling output anyway you want.

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution is to use for loop for this:

```
for file in `grep irl "keyword" .`; do 
    xmllint --xpath '/HTML/BODY/P[2]' $file;
    echo;
done
```

----  EDIT ----

I'm assuming from your previous comment that `xmllint` does not output a newline.   Added echo to body of loop, which should fix the problem.